# What to do after a bad review with implied message to leave

Tags: job-change, performance-reviews, netherlands, review

I recently got a bad yearly review at my current employer, and I actually don't know what to do.

I already had a question regarding mental health late last year on the platform and that was 1 of the reasons of my bad review (not impliced but it was a outcome). And I also know it almost solely up to me to fix.

Now my question is I have a few options but not sure what to do with them. My first option is better myself but it was implied that that is a long shot.
Second option is ride out my contract and then be let go (with some benefits because of the new laws in the Netherlands).
Third option is looking for a differed job and give notice (this 1 was implied the most). It will still keep the same benefits as the second option this is because of law.

My question is what to do with those options. I work at this employer for a little over a year now and my contract ends in 7 months. i can leave without strings attach (no study fee's or anything else).

Regarding the mental health issue that is dealt with and no longer a problem.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It sounds like you had a rough review. However, it's hard for us to tell you what to do, because the best answer for you will depend on your goals and what is important to you.

Comment: @dwizum i know that you guys/girls cant do that more the question what to do with them

Comment: Did they offer you benefits if you would leave? Option three raises this question for me, cause usually you don't get benefits if you find yourself a different job and give notice. It's not unheard of to make deals with the employer, however.

Comment: @Caroline its a new wierd law in the netherlands i need to look into how it works but basacly i get 2 months of pay if i leave early

Comment: Use a fourth option, start looking for a new job but DO NOT give notice until you've actually gotten a job offer.

Comment: I haven't found anything about this "weird new law". Basically there's three options: 1. you give notice and you serve the notice period (no benefits), 2. they give notice (you get benefits), 3. you make a deal "Wederzijds goedvinden" (benefits whatever is in your deal): https://www.juridischloket.nl/werk-en-inkomen/arbeidscontract-en-werktijden/contract-beeindigen/ Sounds like your employer is looking for option 3 and offering you 2 months of pay

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an easy one. You will need a job anyway in 7 months and your employer doesn't mind if you leave earlier. There is no renewing this contract. There is no benefit for you if you delay.

Do what you can to get better at your job and at the same time look for another one.

Comment: Yes, if your employer is looking to push you out, it's time to go. It's almost always better for your self respect and your resume/CV to leave on your own terms. Even if you currently like you job, they will likely continue to put pressure on you to the point where you hate it. Start looking for a new job while you still like this one and while you still have a job to switch from. It's usually easier to find a job when you're already employed.

Answer (score 6):

Some years ago, I got a hint that my (Netherlands) employer was not going to renew my contract.  I was already looking for a new job anyway and had an interview lined up, so I just accelerated those plans and accepted the job offer when it came.  I managed negotiate my exit and quit, before they had a chance to let me go.

It is easier to move to a new job from a position of having a job, than to be let go and having to answer questions about why you were let go.